# When collectionviewcell is released

Tags: ios, collectionview

I have a collectionview. Whenever I scroll down, some new cells will be generated inside the collectionview. So the concern I have is when iOS release those cells that are already far aways from the screen. I need to get notified, so I can release image data in my data pool.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Collection view cells aren't deallocated during scrolling. Instead, they're put into the reuse pool so the next time you call `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:`, it can return a recycled instance instead of allocating a new one.

To be notified of a cell going offscreen, implement [`collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionViewDelegate_protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UICollectionViewDelegate/collectionView:didEndDisplayingCell:forItemAtIndexPath:) on the delegate of your collection view.

If you need to know when a cell is coming out of the reuse pool, you can implement [`prepareForReuse`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UICollectionReusableView_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UICollectionReusableView/prepareForReuse) on your `UICollectionViewCell` subclass. Don't forget to call `[super prepareForReuse]`.